# Problem on JPA: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jpa

I´m using JPA with SPRING and mySQL and I´m having problems while removing an entity...

I am doing this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

...
    @Transactional

```
public void delete(Long id) {

em.flush();
OwnerEntity e = em.getReference(Entity.class, Long.valueOf(id));

if (e == null)
throw new Exception(Status.SERVER_ERROR);
em.remove(e);
em.flush();
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Well, the error is self explaining: you are supposed to run your JPA code inside a transaction and it looks like you aren't, hence the [`TransactionRequiredException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/TransactionRequiredException.html). From its javadoc:

> Thrown by the persistence provider when a transaction is required but is not active.

There are many ways to handle transactions with Spring, one of them is to annotate your service with `@Transactional` (assuming you have `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your Spring configuration).

Since you didn't tell us much about the way you use Spring for that, I suggest to check the  [Chapter 9. Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks... but now I´m getting another error: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1 .....
Do you now what can be that?

Comment: @Alucard: Can't answer that from what you're showing. You should update your question to 1. show more code. 2. reflect the changes you made 3. provide the whole stacktrace.